# Exporting rotations of selected objects to a text file

Tags: python, text-object

I am using this script which I got from the internet and it works perfectly for 2.79.
Please could someone help adding selected objects rotation to export to the same txt file? In degrees.... Thanks in advance.

```
# import the necessary modules we need
# in our case, blender's python API and python's os module
import bpy, os

# get the current selection
selection = bpy.context.selected_objects

# initialize a blank result variable
result = ""

# iterate through the selected objects
for sel in selection:
    # get the current object's dimensions
    dims = sel.dimensions
    # write the selected object's name and dimensions to a string
    result += "%s - %.03fm x %.03fm x %.03fm\n" % (sel.name, dims.x, dims.y, dims.z)

# get path to render output (usually /tmp\)
tempFolder = os.path.abspath (bpy.context.scene.render.filepath)
# make a filename
filename = os.path.join (tempFolder, "newfile.txt")
# open a file to write to
file = open(filename, "w")
# write the data to file
file.write(result)
# close the file
file.close()
```

Comment: This is kind of hard to read

Answer (score 1):

You already outlined everything that needs to be done. Rotation can be reached at .rotation_euler:

[image]

Note that you can find this information by typing stuff to the console and hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> for auto complete.

The values are in radians so you need an easy way to convert them. You can just multiply the values by 57.29577951308232, or you could do `from math import degrees` or `from math import degrees, radians` so you have functions that can convert between the two for you.

Everything from math is imported in the console so you could just get the degrees of x rotation of the active object by typing `degrees(bpy.context.object.rotation_euler.x)` in the console to check that this indeed does work.

In a script this would look something like:

```
import bpy
from math import degrees

result = ''

for o in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    #something else that you need to get to result
    n = o.name
    r = o.rotation_euler
    result += "%s - X:%.3f, Y:%.3f, Z:%.3f \n" % (n, degrees(r.x), degrees(r.y), degrees(r.z))
    # carry on to do whatever else
#write to file
```

Comment: May be more robust using `o.matrix_world.to_euler()`  will return the visual global rotation of the object.  If the object is rotated via constraint for example `o.rotation_euler` will not reflect this.  Remember too py console has convenience variables `C = bpy.context, D = bpy.data`